# Appending a value to an empty list according to conditions

Tags: python

I have a table with many columns. I am only interested in two columns. Lets call them A and B. I would like to create an empty column, say C = [ ] and append values to it according to some conditions.

```
A   B   
1   10
0   11
0   12
1   09
0   14
0   13
1   12
```

Lets take the above table as an example. **If the value in column A==1 then append the value of B for which A==1 to column C (the empty list) until the next A==1 appears in column A.** For the next value of 1 in column A, do the above.

So I would want my column C to look like this:

```
A   B   C 
1   10  10
0   11  10
0   12  10
1   09  09
0   14  09
0   13  09
1   12  12
```

**So as you can see, for the first A==1,  C has the value of B for which A==1 until the next A==1 appears.**

I was trying something like this, but it is not working:

```
for i in A:
    if i == 1:
        C.append(B[A==i])
```

But this loops through my entire column A and appends many lists.

How can I go about doing it?

Comment: What should happen in `C` if `A` leads with a `0` in the very first row?

Comment: @Cyber My column A has value 1 in the very first row and then has many values of 1 until the last row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
A = [1,0,0,1,0,0,1]
B = [10,11,12,9,14,13,12]

C = []
temp = B[0]   # Initialize a temporary variable to the first item in B

for i in range(len(B)):
    if A[i] == 1:
        temp = B[i]  # Only update temp if 1 was in the A column
    C.append(temp)

>>> C
[10, 10, 10, 9, 9, 9, 12]
```

Walking through a few iterations of the `for` loop:

`i = 0`, `A[0]` is `1`, `temp` becomes `B[0]` which is `10`
`i = 1`, `A[1]` is `0`, `temp` stays `B[0]` which is still `10`
`i = 2`, `A[2]` is `0`, `temp` stays `B[0]` which is still `10`
`i = 3`, `A[3]` is `1`, `temp` becomes `B[3]` which is `9`
... etc

Comment: Could you please elucidate further? So first `i` takes the value 0 and then `A[0]` is 1. So `temp` becomes 10. Then does the loop go again to the `if` statement?

Comment: The statement `if A[i]` will be `True` if it finds a `1` and `False` if it finds a `0`. Please see my edit which walks through a few iterations of how that works.

Comment: So `A[i]` for the first time takes the value 1 and will remain the same till the end of the loop?

Comment: `A[i]` is updated every iteration of the loop, that is how you check each row if A is 0 or 1. But yes, within 1 iteration of the loop, A[i] does not change.

Comment: when `i` becomes 1, how does `temp` stay the same? `temp = B[1]` which should be 11 right?

Comment: No, notice that `temp = B[i]` is in the if statement. If A[i] is 0, that line will not execute, it will skip over changing the value of temp.